# Bundle lazy modules Angular 2

Tags: angular, lazy-loading, angular2-routing

I've seen example of lazy load Angular modules from external files like following:

```
export const AppRoutes: Routes = [
    { path: 'application1', loadChildren: 'application1/main.js' },
    { path: 'application2', loadChildren: 'application2/main.js' },
    { path: 'application3', loadChildren: 'application3/main.js' }
]
```

I'm working in a really large Angular project where we got a root module which contains some global components as well as services that's available throughout the application. All applications as described in the router above is separate projects in separate repos. When deploying an application the js files will be deployed to the correct directory on the web server. I'm trying to figure out how to bundle the application{x}/main.js files but I can't really find any info/examples.

Anyone know were this is documented or if there are some example to look at?